# Conversion to predicates including number

Tags: predicate-logic, real-numbers

How can i convert these sentences into predicates, I'm a little bit confused since it includes numbers in the sentences?

How can i represent the count operation?

$f_1$ : There are $500$ employees in $ABC$ Company

$f_2$ : Employees earning more than $5000$ pay tax

$f_3$ : Managers earns Rs $10,000$

$f_4$ : John is manager in $ABC$ company

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use functions and order operators?   If so, then $\;\color{blue}{\operatorname{earns}(x)>5000}\;$ is a predicate.   If not, then $\color{blue}{\operatorname{EarnsMoreThan} (x,5000)}$ is a predicate.